# Where do I place my open source project heading in my resume?

Tags: resume, professionalism

This kind of structure/template my resume is following this time.  [Resume](https://i.stack.imgur.com/keVMl.jpg)

I just wanted to know which one is a better place in my resume to mention about my open source projects.

One option - Below Work experience and another one is just above skills and hobbies in my resume template.

Let me know which one is more professional and a better option.

Comment: @RhysW lol..yeah..its all personal belief and assumption .nice catch and good to see that u actually read it before giving any answer :)

Comment: I wouldn't suggest having a 'hobby' section on your resume in the first place. As for open source projects, I'd call that work experience.

Comment: Related: I'd rename 'extra curricular activities' to something along the lines of 'continuing education' or the like.

Comment: This is unrelated to your question, but your resume has too many words on it - I'd try to cut out extra words. When I see several sentences under bullet points I am immediately turned off..

Comment: @enderland so do i need to cut some bullet points ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a general approach, I suggest creating a resume section titled something like "Related Volunteer Experience" (use "Community" instead of "Volunteer" if you prefer; other changes can be good too).  In it, you can put open source contributions as well participation in community groups that may be applicable to jobs in which you are interested.  I've done this to show knowledge I gained through volunteering for non-profit organizations; this was especially helpful when I hadn't done similar work in a paid position.

If you wish to keep your resume organized as it currently is, my recommendation would be to put your open source experience into the section titled "Extracurricular Activities and Achievements".  Once someone has gained some professional experience, at least some experts recommend omitting a hobbies section, unless it would be directly relevant to a resume customized for a particular job.  Thus, it seems to me that such a section is likely to be ignored. YMMV, of course.

Answer (score 3):

I would say it goes in skills and hobbies.

Technical Skills is reserved for the things such as the languages you know / the frameworks you use.

work experience tends to have to be experience gained in the corporate world, e.g 4 years with company X doing projects A, B and C.

As working on open source is not corporate work for a specific company, nor is it a specific technology i would say that leaves hobbies and skills. As your hobby is contributing to open source projects.

However if your contribution was done on work time, for a specific project i would say you could get away with listing it as work experience. It comes down to when you did it, on your time or on company time.